c++ What happens to a variable's origin memory address when assigned to a pointer?
I'm trying to figure out the details of using pointers and references.
Here I've left some comments that can show my train of thought:
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ref; // A variable at an unknown memory address (lets call the address X)
    int *point; // An empty memory address (lets call the address Y)

        ref = 3; // An int 3 is stored at address X
        point = &ref; // Address Y now contains 'ref'

        //What happened to address X? Are there two addresses now, known and unknown?

    cout << point << endl;  //prints address Y
    cout << *point << endl; //prints address Y contents (3)
    cout << ref << endl; //prints 3 from ?
    
    return 0;
}


Try this:  cout << ref << " " << (void *) (&ref) << endl; -- print the address of the ref variable.

You can have 5 different things pointing to X (the address of ref) and there is still only 1 X.  Assigning point = &ref doesn't change X, it just gives you a second way to read from or write to the same X that you created by declaring int ref.

I'm confused about what you think address Y is (and I think you are too). You said '//Address Y now contains 'ref''. That's not true, a better statement would that the pointer variable point now contains the address X. '//prints address Y', no it prints the address X. 'cout << *point << endl; //prints address Y contents (3)'` no it prints the contents of address X.

One common cuase of confusion is some incorrect belief about pointer variables. A belief that they are somehow special and different rules apply to them compared to regular variables. You seem to have some variety of that belief, but it's not true, pointer variables are just regular variables. They can have values (or not) and they can get assigned to, when they are assigned to they lose their previous value, just like regular variables.

@DaveS Copy that - It makes sense now, thanks!

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does; use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Just to confuse you even more:  the compiler is allowed to place variables into registers, so that there is no memory usage.

"What happened to address X?" -- I don't follow this question. Why should something happen to X just because you did not directly mention it in the preceding line? Why wouldn't "int 3 is stored at address X" still be true?

An empty memory address (lets call the address Y) should read A variable at an unknown memory address (lets call the address Y), and Address Y now contains 'ref' should be Address Y now contains address X

The line:
cout << ref << endl;

prints 3 from the memory, allocated for ref variable which is located in your terminology at memory address X. Actually it is allocated in automatic storage (commonly, on stack) and has lifetime of variable ref which is the body of function main.
Nothing could happen exactly "to address X", it is the value that is stored at the "address X" was initialized (had some random value) and later the value 3 was assigned to it. The same happened with the pointer Y, it contained some initial random address and later was set to point to X.

So there are essentially two places in memory that update when changing ref from there on... Say ref = 7; //Two memory addresses updated: X (unknown) and Y (known)?

No. Only 1 variable is updated. point points to the same 1 location where ref stores its value.

Ahhh I think I see... So point = &ref; obtained the (formerly unknown) memory address of ref?
If that's correct, what was point before it pointed to ref? Just an empty address that is lost once point is actually pointing?

@CodeN00b point's value before the assignment was indeterminate. Could have been anything, and that's a very explosive state. In general it is best to not have an initialized variable lying around where some kid could find it, so avoid defining a variable before you know that it's value will be. Eg: int *point = &ref;

Got it - sounds scary :'D
Thank you both!

Two comments up: to not have an initialized variable should have been to not have an uninitialized variable. Sorry 'bout that.

@CodeN00b, you are right; updated the answer.
